# Make MongoDB Spring Boot test use existing configuration and embedded test database

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, unit-testing

this is my existing MongoDB configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MongoDBProperties mongoDBProperties;

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(mongoDBProperties.getUrl());
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Override
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new OffsetDateTimeReadConverter(), new OffsetDateTimeWriteConverter()));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return mongoDBProperties.getDatabase();
    }
}
```

I need the converters because the document that I store contains OffsetDataTime fields.

I want to test saving a document. I have included this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My test looks like this:

```
@DataMongoTest
public class VersionRepositoryTestCase {

    @Autowired
    MyDocumentRepository cut;

    @Autowired
    MongoDBProperties mongoDBProperties;

    @Test
    public void speichernVonVersionMitVersionInfoFunktioniert() {
        MyDocument myDocument = createMyDocument();
        cut.save(versionDocument);
    }
}
```

My problem is: if I use @SpringBootTest, it is not the embedded MongoDBD that is being used. if I use the @DataMongoTest and override the MongoDbProperties bean, the converters are not used so the test fails. So how can I use my config class with the embedded test mongo db instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with @Import anotation above the Test class.